# How can I accelerate a Dynamic showing a graphic with custom ticks?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The following was adapted from a real world code:

```
ticks = Join[
   Table[{i, Style[i, 10, Background -> White], {.04, 0}}, {i, 0, 20, 
     1}],
   Table[{i, Null, {.01, 0}}, {i, 0, 20, 0.1}],
   Table[{i, Null, {.025, 0}}, {i, 0, 20, 0.5}]
   ];
loc = {1, 1};
LocatorPane[
 Dynamic[loc, loc[[2]] = #[[2]]; &],
 Dynamic@Show[
   Graphics[{Dashed, 
     Line[{{loc[[1]] - 0.5, loc[[2]]}, {0, loc[[2]]}}]}],
   ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {0, 20}}, 
   Axes -> {False, True}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   Ticks -> {Automatic, ticks}
   ]]
```

The problem I have is that when I use the custom ticks, the updating (moving the locator) becomes much slower than with automatic ticks (`Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}`). How can I avoid what I believe is a ticks rebuilding time?

(I do need the `Dynamic@Show[...]` for other updating reasons not shown on this code sample).

Comment: Please provide more information about the `Dynamic@Show` part of your program.  You may very well be able to render a single set of `Ticks` and then overlay your `Graphics`.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you may also be able to move `Dynamic` inside `Graphics`:  `Show[Graphics[Dynamic@{Dashed, ...`

Comment: Can you give a more complete example, that shows why you need `Dynamic` outside the `Show`?  As others have mentioned, you have the potential for a much more responsive graphic if you can push the `Dynamic` further inside.

Comment: I have a function that returns a Graphics object, and so I do:
Show[Graphics[...], myFunction[loc]]

Comment: The alternative to Show is to use First, etc... to extract the parts of the graphic and manually construct a new one.  Especially if the graphic doesn't change, this can be much faster in dynamic situations.

Answer (score 3):

Just as an example of moving `Dynamic` inside:

```
ticks = Join[
   Table[{i, Style[i, 10, Background -> White], {.04, 0}}, {i, 0, 20, 
     1}], Table[{i, Null, {.01, 0}}, {i, 0, 20, 0.1}], 
   Table[{i, Null, {.025, 0}}, {i, 0, 20, 0.5}]];
loc = {1, 1};
LocatorPane[Dynamic[loc, loc[[2]] = #[[2]]; &], 
 Show[Graphics[
   Dynamic@{Dashed, Line[{{loc[[1]] - 3, loc[[2]]}, {3, loc[[2]]}}]}],
   ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {0, 20}}, 
  Axes -> {False, True}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, ticks}]]
```

Without knowing more about the rest of your program I cannot be very helpful.

Comment: I have a function that returns a Graphics object, and so I do: Show[Graphics[...], myFunction[loc]]. Is there a safe way of removing the graphics header of an element in order to add Dynamics in between?

Comment: @P.Fonseca you could use `myFunction[loc]/.Graphics[e_]:>Graphics[Dynamic[e]]` instead of just `myFunction[loc]`.